# Почему код не работает?Тут переменная Length =7

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
int length;

length = 7;

cout << " Length = ";
cout << length;

return 0
}
```

Comment: *"не работает"* не является описанием проблемы

Comment: Скорее всего сразу закрывается окно программы? Ну добавьте пресловутую `system("pause");`, если не знаете, как запускать программу в консоли.

Comment: Можете уточнить, что не работает? Если не компилируется, то из-за `return 0`. Должно быть: `return 0;`. Вы забыли точку с запятой поставить после `return 0`

Comment: Я тупанул, и забыл перед 'return 0' поставить ;.Спасибо

Answer (score 1):

Вероятно, проблема в том, что вы забыли поставить точку с запятой после `return 0`. Должно быть: `return 0;`.